# Autoincrement url for anchor link

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make anchor links for different sections in the page.

#section1
 #section2

But, the url isn't being updated each time I click the href link

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
     $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
 }
 <?php echo '<a href = "#section'.($_SESSION['counter']++).'">'.'Next Section'.'</a>';?>
```

When I echo the counter I can see it being updated upon refresh but I want to be able update the anchor section without refreshing.

Thank you

Comment: Do this client-side with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually increment the value in the session and not just what is currently stored in the session.

```
 // If there is a value in the session, then increment it. 
 if(isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
     $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
 } else {
     $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
 }

// Now, use the value which you have set. 
<?php echo '<a href = "#section'.($_SESSION['counter']).'">'.'Next Section'.'</a>';?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the #section in the url does not increment when I click on the link. From #section1 --> #section2 without having to refresh. Is there anyway to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: if you want to avoid page refresh, you'll have to use Ajax.